# Hiding and showing divs when the amount of divs is unknown

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel

I have a page with multiple posts divs and have a hidden comment form for each post. What is the best way to utilize JQuery/JavaScript to display only the comment form for that post after a button or link is clicked.

```
<div class="post">

  <p>Some Content</p>

  <a href="#" class="commentButton">Comment</a>

  <div class="commentForm" style="display:none"></div>

<div>
```

Comment: do you want to show all on button click or show specific on specific button click?the question is a bit unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.commentButton').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle();
});
```

Delegate the click event to the commentButton which should toggle the commentForm. Inside of the event, move to the next element, and perform a slideToggle(). In this way, clicking on the comment button will both show and hide only the next one.

Further to the point, if you wish to hide all other commentForms so only 1 is open at a time, you can simply add:

```
$('.commentForm').hide();
```

before you perform the `.slideToggle().`

Answer (score 0):

put id in your div

```
<div class="commentForm" id="myID" style="display:none"></div>
```

now in script

```
if(someCondition) {
    document.getElementById('myID').style.display = 'hidden'; 
}else {
    document.getElementById('myID').style.display = 'visible'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`next()` might not always be working because many times an element is not after the button (that triggers the action) itself.

If that is the case you can do the following:

```
$('.commentButton').on('click', function(){
    $(this).parents('.post:eq(0)').find('.commentForm(0)').show();
    // or: fadeIn(500); / fadeOut(500);
    // or: slideToggle(); / slideUp(); / slideDown();
    // or: css('display, 'block'); / none
});
```

This will find it's first parent with the class `post` and than the element inside it with the class `commentForm` even if its inside another element or in another etc.

*In the example of yours you dont nescesaraly need it, but think of just selecting elements that do not have any classes or IDs :)*